# Tomcat7 Stack Size is to small

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I am (was) running Tomcat7 on Ubuntu 12.04 just happily, then I applied the security updates for ubuntu and now Tomcat will not start. The error I am getting in catalina.out is

```
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've done some googling and everything I have found mentioned setting the -Xss value of the JVM higher.

So in /etc/default/tomcat7 I have updated the JAVA_OPS value to be

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xss1024k -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

But I am still getting the error.

How do I increase the Stack Size for Tomcat7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to set JAVA_OPTS in a startup script so it's easy to configure

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.rwsol.util.protocol"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss2m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
echo "startup with $JAVA_OPTS"

sh run.sh #start the server
```

Then I can have several I can use to configure each project I want to start.

BTW, those are my values in the script

Comment: I've installed Tomcat7 via apt-get and it created all the scripts. I did however create a setenv.sh in there if I set the value in JAVA_OPTS it did not work, but if I set it CATALINA_OPTS it did. I still don't know why it was not being taken from the /etc/default/tomcat7 file.

Comment: That's interesting. CATALINA_OPTS is supposed to be applied to start and run, and JAVA_OPTS is supposed to be applied to start, stop and run. So I always use JAVA_OPTS. I just like the script to easily have multiple configurations available.